# Elasticsearch Nest filtering by multiple values

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

from FE part i have array of values by which i need to filter elastic search query.

For example
from FE part i have query like this order=asc&skip=0&take=25&filter.state=free&filter.state=busy
I parsed it and paste into model like this

```
public class Search 
{
 public string Search { get; set; }

        public string Sort { get; set; }

        public OrderBy? Order { get; set; }

        public int Take { get; set; }

        public int Skip { get; set; }

       public Filter Filter {get;set;}
}

public class  Filter 
{
  public IEnumerable<string> statuses {get;set;}
}
```

And i need to create search by filter states in my elasticsearch

Comment: Please share an example, and what you tried.

Comment: @Paulo i'm updated description

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for "should"

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "gender": "male"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "gender": "female"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

OR

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "gender": "male"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "gender": "female"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but i dont know how to do this in Nest

Comment: @EgorAntonovich https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.17/bool-queries.html


var searchResults = this.Client.Search<Project>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(
                bs => bs.Term(p => p.Name, "x"),
                bs => bs.Term(p => p.Name, "y")
            )
        )
    )
);